# Shell command works in shell, but not when when fired from Python subprocess

Tags: python, shell, phantomjs

I am trying to execute a shell command from a Python script.
I have tried the usual suspects, subprocess.call, Popen, os.system etc.

The command i am trying to execute is admittedly rather long (7k characters), since one of the parameters is a json string. From what I've read length should not be the issue here.

The command looks like this:

```
phantomjs /some/path/visualizer_interface.js -path /another/path/chart.svg -type chart_pie -id 0 -language de -data '{...}'
```

The visualizer interface is a script i wrote myself, that basically renders a requested chart in a Phantom JS context, grabs the svg and writes it to the specified path. When i execute the exact same command i get a flawless chart, but in Python the subprocess never return, and i don't get any form of feedback, not even on the subprocesses stdout.

```
with open('/home/max/stdout.txt', 'w') as out:
    res = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=out)
res.wait()
```

I am able to execute other shell commands, so it's not a fundamental Python problem.

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had a very slight error in the phantomjs script, that behaved differently depending on where it was executed.